# Why is $\displaystyle \int F\cdot ds = \displaystyle\int F\cdot v dt$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, integration

I don't want the argument depending on algebraic manipulations of infinitesimals but rather the substitution needed for the integral to obtain this result.

Comment: $\int F ds = \int F \frac{ds}{dt} dt = \int Fv\,dt$?

Comment: @BySymmetry I explicitly said that I don't want the answer you just posted as it depends on infinitesimals which are not rigorously defined in standard analysis

Comment: It is not clear what you do want. What exactly do you mean by wanting "the substitution"? The result is just applying the substitution rule with $s$ as a function of $t$.

Comment: It's sufficient to prove $\int F_ids_i=\int F_iv_idt$, where $i\in\{1,\,2,\,3\}$ is fixed; we're not [summing over $i$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). As @BySymmetry noted, this is just ordinary integration by substitution. Perhaps what you need clarified is [why substitution works without relying on infinitesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Proof).

Comment: To try and clarify what I struggling with in answering this, integration by substitution is just an algebraic manipulation. So currently your question more or less reads "How do I do this algebraic manipulation without just showing me the algebraic manipulation?". Is there a different way for you to phrase what the difficulty you are having is?

Comment: When you use "ds" that is just the definition of line integral, by using "v dt" you are using a particular parametrization of the path "s(t)". Every time you do such an integral "for real" you need a parametrization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have
$$
\int_{s(t_0)}^{s(t_1)} F(s)\cdot ds  = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}F(s(t))\cdot s'(t)dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}F(s(t))\cdot v\cdot dt 
$$

which is exactly the definition of integral substitution in standard analysis.

(I'm referring to [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_durch_Substitution) definition of substitution, i.e. $\varphi(t) = s(t))$